# opencv memory leak in equalizeHist?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, histogram

I am running a process in ~20000 images. It was crashing every time at a different point, so I decided to debug it. 
After a few debugging I have realized about this:

[image]

[image]

I've just create a dummy function that equalizes an image and when it goes out of the scope it does not release all the memory.
I have tried with:
equalizedImage.release() but same result.

Any idea about what to do or if I am not managing something correctly??

(using Opencv version 2.4.9)

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you think that the program crashes because of memory leak? Does memory consumption increases proportionally to number of processed images?

Comment: Yes, it does. The memory use increases with the number of processed images

Comment: Does the crash come with any message?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't indicate that the src and dest can be the same image.

Comment: Same issue when src and dest are different images

Answer (score 1):

I hate not to be able to comment for this, but I want to note a few things.

1) Windows' Task Manager memory usage indicator cannot be fully trusted for this purpose. The Process is free to keep some memory reserved for future use.

2) Please post the code that leaks so we can reproduce it properly. Possibly with tools like Valgrind the leak can be detected. At least that is better than the Task Manager.

3) Have you considered upgrading to the latest release of OpenCV to see if this behavior disappears?

4) I highly doubt that this has something to do with your crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and should not cause any leak. The problem is somewhere else. However, there is common problem when linking openCV wrongly with your program (for example linking with MT while your program is MD or another wrong configurations) that cause a problem in releasing cv::Mat. This problem usually appears in the Debug mode and disappeared in the Release mode. so you may try to debug it in the debug mode. This problem may prevent Mat from being freed correctly.

BTW, what is the memory usage you are getting after 1000 epochs?